How many ways can you select a certain number of 50 balls and place them into 5 boxes?
Balls are indistinguishable, boxes are distinguishable.
Do i understand this correctly?
For k balls there are $\binom{k +4}{4}$ possibilites, and k can be a number between 0 and 50.
So the answer will be sum of $\binom{k +4}{4}$ for k <0, 50>?
Also I was wondering why can't we think of another box that will contain balls that aren't in other boxes, so the answer would be $\binom{50 +5}{5}$

Yes, you can, and should, for the simplest solution

Take a look at this formula:
$$\sum_{j=k}^n\binom{j}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
Substituting $n=54$ and $k=4$ shows that both your answers are equivalent.

thanks! i didnt know about this formula, what is it called?

It's a special case of Vandermonde's identity (or Vandermonde's convolution).

See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity
